# How in Django upload Photo based on Gallery name from other model field?

Tags: python, django

I try to save images in media using gallery name which is specified during photo upload. My code is following:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    upload_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "galleries"

class Photo(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    File = models.FileField()
    PhotoGallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.File.upload_to = "{media}/photohouse/{gallery}".format(media=settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                                                               gallery=self.PhotoGallery.name)
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The image is still uploaded to root media. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`upload_to` needs to a callable and specified as part of your model field.

```
def photo_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return '{media}/photohouse/{gallery}/{filename}'.format(
        media=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 
        gallery=instance.PhotoGallery.name,
        filename=filename)

class Photo(models.Model):
    ....
    File = models.FileField(upload_to=photo_upload_to)
```